# Can I know when / if user disabled "background activity" in API level 26(Oreo)?

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I am not targeting 26, but I want to know when the user disabled 'background activity', as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#overview) (to show a notification when it happens).

Is there some intent I can listen to? or some other way to programmatically know if it is currently disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to know if the user disabled the 'background activity'.
Not sure that it is the best solution, but looks like it is working:

At onDestroy of my sticky service, I scheduled a job (with JobScheduler) with time limitations.

When the job runs, I check that my sticky service is still being destroyed, and not started again. 
If this is the case, I try to start the service from the job, and check for success:

```
ComponentName componentName = startService(serviceIntent);
if(componentName == null){
    // we could not start the service, so user probably disabled the background activity
}
```